# How to kill a thread in python with blocking command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, interactive-brokers

I want to use Interactive Brokers' API which opens a TCP connection on a different thread.
The problem is that the app.run() function what needs to be called to establish the TCP connection probably uses a while true loop for processing it's queue, what block every possible way I know to terminate the thread when exiting the program.

```
class TradeApp(EWrapper, EClient): 
    def __init__(self): 
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    #...

def websocket_con():
    app.run()
    
app = TradeApp()      
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=1)
con_thread = threading.Thread(target=websocket_con, daemon=True)
con_thread.start()
```

I've tried using a daemon thread and simple one.
I've tried to use events also.
But whatever I do, it seems the thread will never exit from the execution of app.run() function.

```
class TradingApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    #...

def websocket_conn():
    app.run()
    event.wait()
    if event.is_set():
        app.close()

event = threading.Event()
app = TradingApp()
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=1)

conn_thread = threading.Thread(target=websocket_conn)
conn_thread.start()

#...

event.set()
```

Am I doing something wrong?
How could I exit from app.run() function?

Comment: Have you tried app.disconnect()?  It's an EClient method.

Answer (score 0):

I think u bad understand multiprocessing, when u start `websocket_conn()` function by new process, this new process will be executed step by step so `event.wait() if event.is_set():` doesn't execute before `app.run()` wasn't over.

Try something like this:

```
conn_thread = threading.Thread(target=websocket_conn)
conn_thread.start()

event.wait()
if event.is_set():
        conn_thread.kill()
```

Comment: Yes, that's what exactly the problem is. It's impossible to create a good thread function if the `app.run()` blocks every other executions or event signaling. The above example just shows that events will not help and daemon thread will also not solve the problem. The conn thread will run forever after the main thread has finished it's execution.